Clerk webhook triggering "user.deleted" by default
Why is clerk webhook triggering the "user.deleted" event by default. It keeps on deleting my user database in mongodb. When the "user.created" event creates a user for me, the "user.deleted" event will delete it automatically.
I've console.log the evt.type to see what the error is, but I could see it's in the webhook

I made a mistake by writing a delete query after I wrote a create query in clerk webhook. I have rectified the issue. My application is working fine now. Thank you

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
